# android how to get every row's imageview

Tags: android, listview

I am having custom Listview. Every row in listview contains image and textview.

After finishing the page I want to execute a thread which will get the reference of all the rows then will extract imgeview and set resource image as lazy loading image.

I just want to know how to get every row's image view so that I can set image resource in it. Any idea ????

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like you want to make a custom Adapter (specifically, [BaseAdapter](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/BaseAdapter.html), not a custom ListView.  When you create your own BaseAdapter you can use it to customize how each row is rendered in a regular ListView, by implementing Adapter's `getView().`